# How to call function in laravel controller from codeigniter view?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

My view Codeigniter is like this :

```
<form id="search_form_hotel" name="search_form" method="post">
...
</form>

...

<script>
...
$.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel',
        type: "post",
...
</script>
```

This :

```
  url: base_url + 'hotel_booking/hotel/search_hotel',
```

hotel : controller name in laravel framework

search_hotel : method name in laravel framework

Whether it can call a function in the laravel controller from codeIgniter view?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. Inject controller's function in views are completely outside of arquitectura. Also, laraval does not register the routes in the same way as codeigniter does.

In codeigniter the url pattern defines the structure of a controller, however in laravel you are need to register every route separately without taking in consideration the url format.